# My Mongo queries slow down significantly after the first few queries. Why does this happen?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am writing a data quality script on a large Mongo database that contains about 10 collections, with the largest of them containing about 7 million records. The purpose of the script is to catch errors/inconsistencies in the database and display them in a dashboard. To do this I’m having to run some fairly complex queries and aggregations, some involving multiple lookup/match stages. I'm running this script as a cron job every 24 hours.

The problem that I’m having is that the script slows way down after a few queries. The first few queries might run quickly, but then after 3 or 5 or even 10 queries it slows down to a point where it becomes untenable to run. I can trace the slowdown to the Mongo queries specifically — I’ve tried running the same set of queries in the Mongo shell directly and I’m getting the same slowdown. The slowdown does not seem related to any specific query — the same exact query may take 5 minutes one time, and 70 minutes another time. I’ve tried adding some indexes on the most frequently used fields, but that didn’t seem to make much of a difference.

I am using Mongo version 3.2.6 on Ubuntu.

Anyone have ideas on what might be going on here, or even just how to go about debugging this? I am somewhat proficient with Mongo queries, but am very much a novice at Mongo administration and setup, and this feels like it might be an administration/setup issue. Perhaps Mongo is doing heavy caching or some other issue like that? I could be totally off base here though, just hypothesizing.

Below are a few sample queries of the kind that I’m running, in case that helps. These are some of the more complex queries I'm running, there are much simpler ones as well.

```
db.lots.aggregate([{"$match": {"estimate_high": {"$nin": ["", null]}, "estimate_low": {"$nin": ["", null] } } },
    {"$project": {"_id": 1, "estimate_high": 1, "estimate_low": 1, 
       "estimates_valid": {"$and": [
           {"$gt": ["$estimate_high", 0]},
           {"$gt": ["$estimate_low", 0]},
           {"$gte": ["$estimate_high", "$estimate_low"]}
       ] } } },
   {"$match": {"estimates_valid": false }}, {"$out": "answer"}])


db.lots.aggregate([
        {"$match": { "artwork_id": {"$nin": ["", null]} } },
        {"$lookup" : { 
            "from": "artworks", 
            "localField": "artwork_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "artwork_matches"
            }
        },
        {"$project": {"_id": 1, "artwork_id": 1, "num_artworks": {"$size": "$artwork_matches"}}},
        {"$match": {"num_artworks": 0}}, {"$out": "answer"}
    ])

db.lots.aggregate([
        {"$match": { "artwork_id": {"$nin": ["", null]} } },
        {"$lookup" : { 
              "from": "artworks", 
              "localField": "artwork_id",
              "foreignField": "_id",
              "as": "artwork_matches"
         } },
         {"$unwind": {"path": "$artwork_matches"}},
         {"$unwind": {"path": "$artwork_matches.creators"}},
         {"$lookup" : { 
              "from": "subjects", 
              "localField": "artwork_matches.creators.subject_id",
              "foreignField": "_id",
              "as": "artist_matches"
         } },
         {"$unwind": {"path": "$artist_matches"}},
         {"$match": {"artist_matches.approved": false}},
         {"$project": {"_id": 1, 
                        "artist_name": "$artist_matches.name", "artist_approved": "$artist_matches.approved", 
                        "artwork_title": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$artwork_matches.titles", 0]}}},
         {"$project": {"_id": 1, "artist_name": 1, "artist_approved": 1, 
                     "artwork_title": "$artwork_title.text"}},
                {"$out": "answer"}
])

db.lots.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"price": {"$lte": 300, "$gt": 0} } },
        {"$lookup" : { 
            "from": "sales", 
            "localField": "sale_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "sale_matches"
        } },
        {"$unwind": {"path": "$sale_matches", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}},
        {"$lookup" : { 
            "from": "currencies", 
                     "localField": "sale_matches.currency_term_id",
                     "foreignField": "_id",
                     "as": "currency_matches"
        } },
        {"$unwind": {"path": "$currency_matches", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}},
        {"$project": {"_id": 1,
            "orig_value": "$price", 
            "base": "$currency_matches.label", "date": "$sale_matches.date",
            "price_usd": "$price_usd",
            "price_eur": "$price_eur",
            "price_gbp": "$price_gbp",
            "price_hkd": "$price_hkd",
            "price_chf": "$price_chf"
        } }
    ])
```

Comment: What does mongostat show during those queries? I expect lots of faults and high lock percentage.

Comment: Hey Sergio - I am indeed seeing lots of faults in mongostat when running these queries, 2000 to 3000 faults per second. I am not seeing any lock percentage entries in the mongostat output though (I'm running mongo v3.2)... So what does this mean? What should I be doing differently to avoid this behavior?

Comment: This means you should get more ram.

Comment: Hmm, went up from 8GB to 16GB, and that didn't seem to make a difference...Any other thoughts?

Comment: How big is your dataset?

Comment: From dbStats output -"collections" : 33,
 "objects" : 19905894,
 "avgObjSize" : 2141.0786308818883,
 "dataSize" : 42620084272,
 "storageSize" : 47559765856

Comment: So you have a dataset of 42 gb. And you only have 16 gb of ram. Depending on your access patterns, it might be not enough. if the faults/sec don't die down, this means you're constantly requesting data that is not in memory. If this is the case, you need enough ram to hold all of data + indexes.

Comment: It also doesn't help if there's another memory hog on that machine, which competes with mongod for precious ram.

Comment: There is nothing else running on this machine -- just mongod and the data quality queries that I described. And what's more, the queries run one at a time -- my script waits for a query to return before running another one.

Comment: Yeah well, those queries _do_ look like full scans. I'd need to see some explain plans to be sure.

Comment: If it is a ram issue -- wouldn't you expect a particular query to always take roughly the same amount of time -- since the query's working set is the same each time? What would explain the behavior I described, where the same query takes 5 minutes one time and 70 minutes another time? I can definitely try just throwing more ram at the problem, but I hesitate to do that until I have a clearer understanding of what's going on.

Comment: "same query takes 5 minutes one time and 70 minutes another time" - this is easy. First time it had most of the needed data in memory. And by the second time, some other query had flushed that data to disk, so it has to be reloaded.

Comment: Show me a query plan: `db.lots.find({"estimate_high": {"$nin": ["", null]}, "estimate_low": {"$nin": ["", null] } }).explain()` (post to gist or something. Will be unreadable in comments)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pevzner/260370c1274143ed7867622838d8fb0a

Comment: And another one, for one of the aggregate/lookup queries: https://gist.github.com/pevzner/ac77adf3ad232bdc81fab07bcb3e331f

Comment: Yeah, you see COLLSCAN there? Bad news, if you only have 16 gb ram for 42 gb dataset.

Comment: The working set for the COLLSCAN would be the "lots" collection rather than the entire dataset, wouldn't it? db.lots.stats() says "count" : 6362587,
 "size" : 12382188880,
 "avgObjSize" : 1946,
 "numExtents" : 28,
 "storageSize" : 12978614224,
 "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864, "totalIndexSize" : 1437929472.

Comment: Ah, right. But you do aggregate or other queries on other collections, right? If you're using mmap storage engine, it's more or less "least recently accessed data sits in ram". The nature of the high faults/s is that mongo tried to find data in memory but failed, so now it has to load from disk, which is super-slow.

Comment: Oh yeah it does look like I'm using mmap...Do you think it would help if I switch to wiredTiger?

Comment: Yeah, it should help somewhat. Just don't try it in production right away :)

Comment: :) ok will try this out on an isolated instance, hopefully that does the trick. thanks!

Comment: Let me know how it went :)